# Why is my code needs to loop and not end?

Tags: python, tkinter

**stuff in bold isn't code.
Need help with tkinter to make a simple box.
I need it so if it closes it reactivates**

```
from tkinter import *
myWindow = Tk()
button1 = Button(myWindow, text="Ya like Jazz?")

while True:
    f = open("Who.txt", "r")
    g = f.read()
    if g == "0":
        button1 = Button(myWindow, text="Ya like Jazz?")
        button1.pack()
        myWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your first three lines create a simple dialog box.  If you just add `button1.pack()` and `myWindow.mainloop()` after that, it will display your dialog.  If you want to take some action when the user closes the dialog, then you have to add a handler for the window close event.  Note that having it open itself again is going to irritate your users.

Comment: i don't understand, I only need my code to stop doing this error       can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed

Comment: Do you understand why you get that?  `mainloop` exits when the main window is closed and Tk is shut down.  To start over again, you need to reinitialize Tk. Move the "myWindow = Tk()` line inside your `if` statement, and delete the first `button1 =...` line, since you create it later.

Answer (score 0):

This displays your dialog 3 times the exits.

```
from tkinter import *

i = 0
while True:
    if i < 3:
        i += 1
        myWindow = Tk()
        button1 = Button(myWindow, text="Ya like Jazz?")
        button1.pack()
        myWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tim, You have fixed and helped me so much. thank you a lot sir